# Migrating IBM worklight 6.2 to MobileFirst 8

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

We have developed a worklight 6.2 application which is in production, now we are requested to add a new module and migrate the existing application to mobilefirst v8. Kindl advice, if it is advisable to migrate from 6.2 to 8 directly, and provide us any links which would help us to understand more.

Thanks

Comment: this should be your starting point https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/upgrading/migration-cookbook/  if you have any specific questions , let us know

Comment: Hi Kavitha, Thanks for the input. So we need to migrate to 7.1 first and then to 8.0. right?

Comment: No need to do it in 2 steps, Please go through the features used in your environment and attempt using the migration cookbook to see what is the alternative in MFP8. cookbook covers migrating from any version starting 6.2  ... 7.1 to MFp 8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be your starting point https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/upgrading/migration-cookbook/  for migrating to 8.0 from any older version starting from MFP 6.2 (/6.3/7/7.1).